# Как получить и изменить часовую поправку?

Tags: java, android

Используя класс Date, заметил что при форматировании даты, этот класс использует часовую поправку из настроек девайса. Можно ли получить эту поправку и изменить на время использования класса, а потом вернуть обратно?

Или есть другой класс для форматирования с учетом часовой поправки?

UPD:

```
Date date = getDate(datejul); //перевожу из юлианской в обычную
```

Форматирую

```
SimpleDateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String TimeStr = frmt.format(date);
```

Форматирование происходит с часовой поправкой взятой из устройства, а мне надо чтобы с моей поправкой (например TZ=2.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` как бы умеет:

```
      SimpleDateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
      frmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+02:30"));
      String TimeStr = frmt.format(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Как мне представляется решение вашего вопроса. Необходимо выяснить ТаймЗону

```
TimeZone tzMoscow = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow");
System.out.println(tzMoscow);//sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Moscow",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=79,lastRule=null]

TimeZone tzLA = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
System.out.println(tzLA);//sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
```

Затем запросить используется ли летнее время, значение `Boolean`

```
Boolean dayLightMoscow = tzMoscow.useDaylightTime();
System.out.println(dayLightMoscow);//false

Boolean dayLightLA = tzLA.useDaylightTime();
System.out.println(dayLightLA);//true
```

В зависимости от `true` или `false` складываете или минусуете исходную величину.

Comment: Добавил UPD для уточнения вопроса.